# What is the standard mandated behavior of std::promise's destructor after calling set_value_at_thread_exit?

Tags: c++11

If you destroy an std::promise whose shared state is not yet ready, but for which someone has called `set_value_at_thread_exit` (and that thread has not yet exited), what is the expected result?

As best I can tell, the destructor for the promise should store a future_error exception (with code broken_promise) into the shared state.  However, this does not appear to be the behavior for GNU/libstdc++, which will yield the stored value (and not throw an exception) on a call to the future's `get()`.

I've come to my conclusion based on my reading of cppreference's descriptions for `std::promise::set_value_at_thread_exit`:

> Stores the value into the shared state without making the state ready immediately. The state is made ready when the current thread exits, after all variables with thread-local storage duration have been destroyed.

and for `std::promise::~promise`

> Abandons the shared state:
>
> - if the shared state is ready, releases it.
> - if the shared state is not ready, stores an exception object of type 
>     std::future_error with an error condition std::future_errc::broken_promise, makes the shared state ready and releases it.

For example code:

```
#include <future>

void foo(std::promise<int> p)
{
  p.set_value_at_thread_exit(42);
  // p is destroyed here
}

int main()
{       
  std::promise<int> p;
  std::future<int>  f = p.get_future();
  std::thread t(foo, std::move(p));
  t.join();
  (void)f.get(); // Throw future_error or return 42 ?
}
```

Comment: Your promise does not have thread-local storage duration, the first quote does not apply. (Also note cppreference example is pretty much the same as yours)

Comment: I don't see where it mentions that the promise has to have thread storage duration for the first quote to apply.  Can you point me to a reference or give me the relevant section from the standard?

Comment: 30.6.5 [futures.promise]p21 as well as the quoted cppreference paraphrase talks about thread-local storage (and its sequencing wrt state becoming ready), nothing about destruction of the promise object. Regardless, if it were to post exceptions in this case, the function would have been useless.

Comment: I agree that under my original interpretation, the *_at_thread_exit functions are rather useless when used with promises with automatic or thread storage duration.  However, they would still be useful with promises with static or dynamic storage duration.  Regarding the first quote regarding, I was mostly focusing on: "the state is made ready when the current thread exits"; the ordering w.r.t the destruction of thread storage duration objects seemed unimportant in this case.